# ndiswrapper wireless driver does not connect to detected Wifi network

Tags: software-installation, wifi, drivers, puppy-linux

I am running Slacko Puppy v5.3.1 and am trying to use my Wifi dongle with it.

I have a Windows `.inf` file for the driver for my USB dongle. I used the Puppy network wizard to load the driver using `ndiswrapper`. It all seemed to be going well until I tried to configure my wireless network. The network is detected but I cannot connect. I cannot figure out why. Any suggestions?

*Note*: the installation CD came with code for Linux but [I am having trouble](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36967/lib-modules-2-6-37-6-build-missing-in-linux-puppy-what-should-i-do) trying this option, too.

Comment: Please give more details: Exact distribution and version, x86 or x86_64, what kind of USB dongle is it (make, model, what does `lsusb(1)` say).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found `ndiswrapper` with Windows drivers to be consistently reliable for wireless adapters on Linux. Likely the driver is not functioning 100% properly when wrapped. Frankly, it's tough to wrap a driver meant for one OS to function smoothly on another, because drivers are so low-level—i.e. they exist at a level of abstraction in which differences between OSes are marked. Confirm that your Wifi dongle is known to work with the `ndiswrapper` driver you are using, or better yet, concentrate your effort on getting the native driver to compile.